# SASS error: Properties arent allowed at the root of a document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, sass

I keep getting an error like this: 
Sass::SyntaxError: Properties aren't allowed at the root of a 
document. 
on line 2 of /Users/eumir/rails_apps/neo2/public/stylesheets/sass/ 
main.sass

main.sass's line 2 starts with

```
@import mixins
```

I have a _mixins.sass which has a variable declaration on line 2:

```
$alt_site_color: #060 
$main_site_color: #ff9900
```

so i was really stumped as to what was making the error happen. I 
tried changing the placing of the variables 4 lines down and i got

Sass::SyntaxError: Properties aren't allowed at the root of a 
document. 
on line 6 of /Users/eumir/rails_apps/neo2/public/stylesheets/sass/ 
main.sass

so I tried deleting the variable declarations and the error stopped 
appearing. What's wrong with my variable declaration?

Also, I keep trying to compile the sass file by using sass --watch and 
sass public/stylesheets/main.sass and i get no errors. BUT when i view 
it in my browser, the error appears. What seems to be the problem?

*note: I have also already uninstalled all my other versions of 
sass(im upgrading from haml2.2.22 to haml 3). I am also using the old 
indented yml style syntax so im veering away from doing the 
sass2convert thing as much as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: i'm getting a similar message, using PHamlP in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had 2 haml folders in my vendor plugins(haml and 
haml2.2.22) deleted both of them and it worked(so im obviously using 
my own gem(haml 3.o)

I guess I'll just have to vendorize it again. 
Still, I'm very curious as to what that error was about though